# How to convert a .txt file to a .url file in R?

Tags: r, windows, shortcut-file

I create a text file below:

```
myFile<-file("toGoogle.txt")
writeLines(c("InternetShortcut]","URL=http://www.google.com","IconFile=http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
"IconIndex=0"), myFile)
close(myFile)
```

For clarity the text file now contains the following:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.google.com
IconFile=http://www.google.com/favicon.ico
IconIndex=0
```

[image]

In Windows, if I manually rename the file to "toGoogle.url" I am prompted:

[image]

After saying "Yes" the file is now a usable web link:

[image]

However when I use `file.rename` or any other substitute in R to change the file extension of `toGoogle.txt` it creates a dead web link with a target of `""`.

Is there a simple way out there to create a web shortcut using R? Or how can I change the file extension in R in a way that Windows is going to recognize it?

****Edit:**  Using R to make the url weblink gives this:**

[image]

And opening it prompts me with this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function `file.rename` works for me. And why not use `file("toGoogle.url")` to create a .url file directly.

Comment: It still makes a url file with a dead target "" when I try this. So, using R the web link does not work. But when manually renaming it in the file explorer it works.. I do not know why that is the case

Comment: I edited my post with some more information on how it looks when I create the file in R.

Comment: Did you use the code you put on this page? I find the code `writeLines(c("InternetShortcut]","URL=http://www.google.com","IconFile=http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
"IconIndex=0"), myFile)` may miss '[' before 'InternetShorcut'

Comment: No my code was okay in my script (with the "[") however I managed to make it work. For some reason, it works on my Desktop, but not in my SharePoint/OneDrive folder. Thank you